# Не работает загрузка фото по api vk

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, curl

Фото в папке есть, но возвращает пустой массив *фото*

```
$access_token = Token;
$peer_id = 2000000001;
$photo = '6.jpg';
$url = "https://api.vk.com/method/photos.getMessagesUploadServer?access_token=$access_token&peer_id=$peer_id&v=5.101";

$postparam = array("photo"=> new CURLFile($photo));
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postparam);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8'));
$upload = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($upload);
```